# Complexity of Branch-and-cut algorithm in terms of "Big O"

Tags: complexity, mixed-integer-programming

How can I compute the Big O complexity of the Branch and cut algorithm?
I am solving an integer linear program using MOSEK that includes $M$ binary variables, but I do not know how to calculate the exact complexity.
Is it just O($2^M$)? or are there problems solved at each branching node that have extra complexity to be computed?

Comment: This question cannot be answered in general, without knowing anything about the specific problem you want to solve. Not every problem with $M$ binary variables requires traversing all $2^M$ possible combinations.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth True, but when one speaks about big-O complexity they are often interested in worst-case or average-case bounds, and this provision makes the question well-defined.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Well, yes, maybe. But then *all* integer problems are the same in complexity, when in reality of course they are not!